# How can I read a whole line of input in Assembly?

Tags: string, assembly, char

The only subroutine I know of capable of reading a user's alphabetical input is read_char, but how I want to be able to read the user's whole input of char no matter how long.

I have a vague notion that I have to make memory room to store the whole input or something? I'm really lost as I'm not certain if Assembly has a C++ equivalent of reading strings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of assembly language are you referring to?

Comment: I guess the assembly language that I'm using might be more niche than what anyone else would be familiar with because I'm using a pre-built assembly compiler actually in a Code::Blocks project, and I guess I didn't even consider this might be an issue, but [here's a link to the pre-built CodeBlocks project](http://thumper.laspositascollege.edu/cz/docs/assemblyproject.zip) that I'm using. Requires CodeBlocks. I suspect it might be something my proffessor made/wrote himself. Oh well, I'll ask him my question for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should have a limit when reading input from the user, otherwise your program might not work properly anymore (see [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) for more informations), so making room for the input and ensure the input won't exceed the buffer is *very* important.
Now, to get a string you have to call a [dos interrupt](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a), giving a pointer to your buffer and some other stuff. It will read until a carriage return is met.
But I think your prof wants you to read using his read_char, so (since this is homework), I'll give you a small advice: you have to do a loop and read chars until..